# Return items from an array created using WCF Service

Tags: vb.net, wcf, list, service, arraylist

I am currently utilizing a WCF service (web) to pass values to my application. The service is hosted offsite and I'm communicating with it well. The problem I have is how do I collect the items from an array that's created on the host side?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, It sound like you have the array and don't know what to do with it? In which case its not really a WCF question. Would using a foreach to iterate through the array solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your feedback @patfromcanada; you know the problem wasn't on my end at all, the issue was the service definition wasn't complete on the other end, causing unexpected results, and to a fault I will 2nd, 3rd, 4th guess my code rather than the next :-) Thanks again!